# Add 3D secure verification in stripe in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, stripe-payments

I accept payment via Stripe. I handled all the payment-related queries on the backend. I just need a basic stripe token and authentication key(of my API) to access this API.

Code for accepting payment

```
//if subscription added with user then accept the payment
stripe.customers.create({
    email: token.email,
    source: token.id
})
    .then(customer => {
        const idempotencyKey = uuid();
        stripe.charges.create(
            {
                amount: product.price * 100,
                currency: "usd",
                customer: customer.id,
                receipt_email: token.email,
                description: `Purchased the ${product.name}`,
                shipping: {
                    name: token.card.name,
                    address: {
                        line1: token.card.address_line1,
                        line2: token.card.address_line2,
                        city: token.card.address_city,
                        country: token.card.address_country,
                        postal_code: token.card.address_zip
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                idempotencyKey
            }
        );
    })
```

I searched on google about 3D secure but all solutions seem be of payment_intent hook. How can I add the 3D secure authenticity in stripe.charge method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I add the 3D secure authenticity in stripe.charge method.

You can't.

It's a legacy API and it doesn't support 3D Secure. You have to migrate to using SCA-ready integrations like PaymentIntents(as you mention) or Checkout.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/older-apis#comparing-the-apis

https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication#preparing